# Fetch xml attribute value for a specific node

Tags: c#, xml

```
<root>
 <A testId ="test">
    <B  id="ABC">one
    </B>
    <B id="ZYZ">two
    </B>
    <B  id="QWE">three
    </B>
    <B>four
    </B>
  </A>
</root>
```

Need to extract attribute value of `testId` for the node `<A>`.I'm using following **c#** code but, its throwing null exception.

```
doc.XPathSelectElement("//A/@testId")
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get attributes with XPath (actually `XPathSelectElement` method names states, that its purpose is selecting element). So, you should select element, and then get its attribute (assume you are using Linq to XML. If not I suggest you to start doing this):

```
(string)doc.XPathSelectElement("//A").Attribute("testId")
```

Actually there is no benefit of XPath usage in this case:

```
(string)doc.Root.Element("A").Attribute("testId")
```

Comment: don't you think .value is required after Attribute("testId")?

Comment: @Neel nope - usage of casting is safer than access to `Value` property. If attribute or element is not found, then `.Value` will throw `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have xml file XMLFile1.xml then try below code it will give u result `test`

```
 XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
 var test = xDoc.Root.Element("A").Attribute("testId").Value;
```

Update :-

As suggested by Sergey usage of casting is safer than access to Value property so updated code as below

```
var test = (string)xDoc.Root.Element("A").Attribute("testId");
```